# can't change button width in tableFooterView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    hauptOptionen = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.hauptOptionen = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];

    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Welchen Beruf übern Sie aus?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"In Welcher Alterstufe sind Sie?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Wo liegt Ihr Unternehmen?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Wieviel Beschäftigte hat Ihr Unternehmen?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Bekommen Sie ein 13. Gehalt?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Bekommen Sie ein 14. Gehalt?"];
    [hauptOptionen addObject:@"Wieviele Überstunden machen Sie im Monat?"];

    UIButton *berechnenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    berechnenButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 90, 40); 
    [berechnenButton setTitle:@"Berechnen!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [berechnenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //[myView addSubview:closeButton];

    kategorienAuswahl = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    kategorienAuswahl.delegate = self;
    kategorienAuswahl.dataSource = self;
    kategorienAuswahl.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    kategorienAuswahl.tableFooterView = berechnenButton;

    self.view = kategorienAuswahl;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

but the button is too large

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really add the button to a "backing view". Just make a new `UIView`, add the button to it, and then set the table's footer view to the new `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You **should not** add it as a button. Add it as a `UIView`, and have that button as a subView in that UIView.

or Just implement the

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```